# How to convert jquery to pure js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is the jquery coding. i would to convert the code into pure javascript. How can i convert it into pure javascript? How to convert it to
pure javascript?

```
 $('#tbl_W_CACTUS_1 tr').not(':last').each(function() {
        if (!this.classList.contains('displayNone')) {
            this.classList.add('displayNone');
        }
    });

    //Hide all link first
    $('a[id^="cactus_listing_sso_"]').each(function() {
        this.classList.add('displayNone');
    });

    if (typeof chkbox != 'undefined') {
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkbx_cactus_"]').each(function() {
            if (this != chkbox) {
                this.checked = false;
            }
        });
    }

    if (document.getElementById('W_CACTUS_1_agad') && $('input[type="checkbox"] 
    [name^="chkbx_cactus_"]').length > 0) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkbx_cactus_"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                var agency_group = "agadgroup_" + document.getElementById('W_CACTUS_1_agad').value + 
"_" + this.value;

                $('#tbl_W_CACTUS_1 tr[agad_group="' + agency_group + '"]').each(function() {
                    if (this.classList.contains('displayNone')) {
                        this.classList.remove('displayNone');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `Replace $('selector') with document.querySelector('selector') and then use a for loop to loop through it and add event listeners and stuff.`

Comment: It's not going to be "pure JavaScript" anyway, browser APIs are not part of the language.

Comment: for this one how?   $('#tbl_W_CACTUS_1 tr[agad_group="' + agency_group + '"]').each(function() {
                    if (this.classList.contains('displayNone')) {
                        this.classList.remove('displayNone');

Comment: Please don't just ask us to port code. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What attempts have you made to do this yourself? What hurdles have you faced? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would become something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#tbl_W_CACTUS_1 tr:not(:last-child)').forEach(tr => {
  tr.classList.add('displayNone');
});

//Hide all link first
document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="cactus_listing_sso_"]').forEach((element) => {
  element.classList.add('displayNone');
});

if (typeof chkbox != 'undefined') {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkbx_cactus_"]').forEach((element) => {
    if (element != chkbox) {
      element.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

const cactusAgad = document.getElementById('W_CACTUS_1_agad');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkbx_cactus_"]')

if (cactusAgad && checkboxes.length > 0) {
  checkboxes.forEach(({ checked, value }) => {
    if (!checked) {
      return;
    }
    const agencyGroup = `agadgroup_${cactusAgad.value}_${value}`;

    const trs = document.querySelectorAll(`#tbl_W_CACTUS_1 tr[agad_group="${agencyGroup}"]`);
    
    trs.forEach((tr) => {
      tr.classList.remove('displayNone');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You don't need the if statements around the `classList` add and remove. The api is smart enough to not add duplicate classes and not error if attempting to remove a class that does not exist in the `classList`

Comment: Well seen, updated answer